# Проектирование REST API. Обновление контента на клиенте

Tags: api, rest

Всех приветствую!

Интересует вопрос, как правильно спроектировать API для обновления контента на клиенте (допустим, на мобильном устройстве).

Есть база данных с элементами на сервере. Она "вшивается" в мобильное приложение и используется там. Далее мы изменили какой-либо из атрибутов объекта на сервере или удалили его, нам нужно в отдельном методе update выдать только те элементы, которые были изменены или удалены.

На данный момент склоняемся к некому подобию системы контроля версий. В качестве версии будет использоваться дата последнего обновления. Клиент посылает в заголовке дату последнего обновления у себя и получает нужные элементы.

Есть ли какие-то альтернативные подходы? Гугления на русском и английском пока ни к чему не привели.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если возникает задача синхронизации, одно из стандартных решений — применять паттерн Event Sourcing.

Вкратце, вместо самого объекта вы храните набор изменений и по этому набору восстанавливаете состояние объекта на определённое время. Подобным образом git хранит репозитории, и именно благодаря такой структуре синхронизация репозиториев выполняется достаточно просто.

Детали описаны, например, на хабре:

https://habr.com/ru/post/146429/ — часть 1
https://habr.com/ru/post/149464/ — часть 2